# return a list using grep (or alternative)

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am trying to return a list of "Name", "Exec" and "Icon" fields in /usr/share/applications/*.desktop

I run:

1. `grep Icon= /usr/share/applications/*.desktop | cut -d '=' -f 2`

   Good: Gave the list.

   Bad: Skipped all .desktop files that did not have an Icon= field.

   Question: Instead of being skipped, I want any files without a "Icon=" field to return 0. How do I do this?
2. `grep Exec= /usr/share/applications/*.desktop | cut -d '=' -f 2`

   Good: Gave the list.

   Bad: i) As above, skipped all .desktop files that did not have an Icon= field. ii) These fields often included unwanted characters after a space (eg. %u).

   Question: i) same as a above. ii) How to also include a ' ' delimiter in my command, so it does not return characters after the space?
3. `grep Name= /usr/share/applications/*.desktop | cut -d '=' -f 2`

   Good: Gave the list.

   Bad: Returned text not just for Name= but also GenericName= or anyotherName=

   Question: How to write the command so only "Name=" is returned, not any other field?

EDIT:
Using Mint Cinnamon 20.3
Can 1,2,3 all be done at once in a single command/script, or is there a solution to one of the questions that also fits the criteria of the other questions, in such a way that I only have to replace 'Icon' with 'Exec' with 'Name'.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asking question on text processing, please always include a concrete input example, as close as possible to the actual input you are dealing with, along with the desired output for that input. While your explanation is reasonably understandable, this often helps clarify what to do in edge cases.

Comment: What AdminBee said. Also, please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. Each of your 3 here is a different question. Please pick _one_ and ask the others separately.

Comment: Don't know what you mean? I literally typed the command which is input into the terminal. usr/share/applications contains .desktop files, which contain text. Among which are fields Name=x, Icon=y and Exec=z. As for output, well, put it in your terminal and see! It will give a list, eg:
Audacity
Bluetooth
Bulky
Etc...
My questions relate to problems with the list.
As for multiple questions. Well, 2 includes a question in 1, and all three are related. It's possible someone could come up with a command that answers all three in one, and I only have to replace Icon with Exec with Name.

Comment: Yes, but the results of the commands depend on your system and we don't even know what operating system you are using. Is it Linux? Something else? Even on systems that do have `/usr/share/applications/`, the contents will be completely different depending on what programs you have installed. So to understand what you need, we need to know the output you are expecting. And no, sorry, but while some are indeed related, the questions are different, so please either try to generalize the question, or separate them into multiple posts.

Comment: Unless the question is "how can I do all these things at once", in which case please clarify that. We could give you a script for it, but do also tell us your operating system so we know what tools are available.

Comment: Understood better now. Fixed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples. So far you've provided no input and have described your output but haven't posted actual output.

Comment: This must be the comedy club. Look at steeldriver answer below, he had no problem understanding and providing a solution. I clicked your link for minimal reproducible example. It said provide code. I did. It was concise, and testable. I didn't know how to solve the problem, hence why I'm here, obviously. I gave the input, I gave the commands, I edited the question, I gave a short example output in comments above when asked for it. What you really need is a guide on how to answer questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, in GNU awk:

```
gawk -F'[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*' -v key=Exec '
  BEGINFILE {value = "0"} 
  $1 == key {value = $2; nextfile} 
  ENDFILE {split(value,v,/[[:blank:]]+/); print v[1]}
' /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
```

Change the key as appropriate for the other cases.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly! Thanks so much!